# Android, simply view question about view reset

Tags: android, button, view, reset

I have a button in my activity, when you click the button an if statement is ran against its text label;

```
if(BTN_1.getText()=="firsttext"){
    //do some stuff, then...
    BTN_1.setText("secondtext");
}else if(BTN_1.getText()=="secondtext"){
    //do other stuff, then...
    BTN_1.setText("firsttext");
}
```

Firstly, if I hit the home button and go back to the desktop and then click back onto my app the view has reset its self; if I press the button and leave it in a state where the text of the button is "secondtext", when I return to my app it says "firsttext", how can I stop the view of my app refreshing its self like this?

Secondly, under my XML layout I have defined the buttons text; android:text="firsttext"
But this won't actually match my if statement above, under onCreate of this app I have: BTN_CONNECT.setText("Connect");
But visually the text of the button is exactly the same, why won't it match?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do I start?

- String compares need to be done with `equals()`, not `==`.
- String compares to check your state are bad to begin with. Use an integer/enum to see manage your state.
- Depending on how long you want your state to persist, you can either do it in `Activity.saveInstanceState()` (so it will persist if you change orientation), or in the `SharedPreferences` if you want it to persist forever.
- Don't use hard-coded strings for android:text, use resources, so you can translate them.
- I don't understand your last point.

Comment: +1 for "Where do I start". That's how I was going to start my answer too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply EboMike. I have changed to use equals(), thanks for pointing this out and I am also changing to use string resources instead of hard coded values. After a quick Google I see the mistake I have made here so thanks again for that. 

I have a problem though; I have defined my android:text as "@string/mystr". Under my main class, I can declare a string say strMine and use it; strMine = getString(R.string.mystr); but if I change strMine this isn't reflected on my button who's android:text is set to "@string/mystr" how can I link these values?

Comment: Forgot to say, mystr IS a declared string resource, I didn't miss that out :)

Comment: If you say `button.setText(R.string.mystr)`, the button's string should change to that string, unless there's something weird in your code.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was being clear. My button under layout.xml has android:text="@string/mystr". During my application, how can I update mystr to update the text of my button?

Comment: You don't change string resources. They're read-only. You change the button to use a different string resource.

Comment: @javano: You have the wrong idea about resource files. Files such as strings.xml (and the strings in it) are only meant to be edited at design time and not at runtime. When you use android:text:"@string/myStr" in the layout file you are simply setting the initial (default) text for the button. If you use something like button.setText(strMine) in your code then you change strMine, the button's text isn't automatically updated...you need to call button.setText(strMine) again. Oops, EboMike got to it as I was typing.

Comment: Yeah, but you were a lot more eloquent. Thanks Squonks :)